# How to display a column when a variable is true in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, boolean

I keep getting this error that `res is not defined`, so I am trying to figure out how to run the column code after res is defined like in js you can do `{res && (code)}`.

```dart
Column(
 children: res['rooms'].map((r) => Card(
      'name',
      '${r['messages'][r['messages'].length - 1]['content']}',
      '${r['_id']}'
 )),
),
```

Comment: Use `?` operator. Like `res ? Column(...) : null`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check if your `res` variable is equal to `null`.

This is the non nullable approach to your problem, but you should check to migrate your project to null safety to avoid all those null checks.

```dart
            res == null
                ? Column(
                    children: res['rooms'].map((r) => Card(
                        'name',
                        '${r['messages'][r['messages'].length - 1]['content']}',
                        '${r['_id']}')),
                  )
                : Container(),
```

Answer (score 1):

It can be hard to read ternary expressions sometimes if you have a large widget within a expression. It also requires you to provide an "else" widget.

I approach this with the spread operator, with a single if statement

```dart
Column(
  children: <Widget>[
    if (res != null)
    ...res.map((r) => Card(
        'name',
        '${r['messages'][r['messages'].length - 1]['content']}',
        '${r['_id']}')),
  ],
)
```

Answer (score 1):

Simple use ternary login like this -

```
Container(
    child: res != null
        ? Column(
              children: []
          )
        : SizedBox()  //Use SizedBox instead of Container for better efficiency
)
```

And update the UI again once "res" is populated.